# Multiple #'s on Note 3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

Can the Note 3 have more than 1 number associated with the same phone? Someone gave me their # and then another #. They said it was the same phone.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a [Galaxy Note 3 with dual SIM support](http://www.androidauthority.com/galaxy-note-3-dual-sim-280652/).

Answer (score 1):

Geff [already showed](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/56759/16575) one easy explanation: Dual-SIM devices.

But never mind how many SIMs: I have a single SIM phone which has two numbers assigned. Well, even 3 now. I've got

1. the usual mobile number, plus
2. my provider assigned me a landline number, to which I
3. forward calls from another landline number.

Number 3 clearly shows how it's possible for everybody. Though technically I have to admit, I assume that even #2 is nothing but a call-forward on the provider's end. So it all comes up to your definition of "number assignment".